# List of Children - Sched.h - Kernel

Tags: kernel, children

Where can i find the definition of the "struct list_head children;  /* list of my children */" which is used in sched.h to keep the children of a process?
I need to access the task_struct for a specific child but i don't know how to get a pointer to that and i don't know what the fields of the list of children are...
Thank you i advance.

Comment: We leave this as an exercise for the reader, it's one of the joys of hacking the kernel.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.Any hint on this?For the current process and its parent process i know how to find the task_struct,but i have no idea of how to access the task struct for its children and its siblings.And i have no idea because they are stored in a list for which i don't even know what it contains.Thank you.

Comment: If you look in `include/linux` it will be quite apparent where list_head is defined :)

Comment: Ok.I think i just found it,located in list.h.It is defined as a doubly linked list and contains two pointers next and prev.But this does not help me,because with these pointers i can iterate through that list but i can't find a way to access its task_struct.Any suggestion on this?Thanks again.;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the solution with a little research on the net.I post it for anyone interested on this.

> struct task_struct *task;
>   
> struct list_head *list;
>
> list_for_each(list, &current->children) {
>       
> task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, children);
>       /* task now points to one of current's children */
>   
> }